# South Australian Country

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

I have noticed in South Australia that country folk will ask the question "where are you to" Can someone elaborate on this. I know that basically it means "where are you".

Comment: I've never heard of it before, but I'm assuming it means *Where are you **off** to?* In other words, *Where are you going?*

Answer (score 1):

I lived in Port Augusta, one of SA's main country towns, for three years (many years ago). We had moved from Victoria, and noticed people saying 'to' on the ends of sentences where we thought it wasn't needed. "Where are you to?" means "Where are you?", even though no-one would reply, for example, "I am to in my bedroom".

I didn't ask anyone why they said that. Their answer might have been "Why don't *you* say it?".

Another quirk we noticed was people saying "off of" instead of "off", but that is more widespread.

Comment: People say "where are you to?", "where's it to", etc, in South West England, especially Bristol.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I didn't know that it was a part of any variety of English.